# Search text with agreegate in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to search text in aggregated mongo query but unable to do it. I have applied lots of solutions but nothing is working.
Here is my code...
I have two collections named is "Posts" and "Users". I am applying aggregate on Posts collection.
E.g.

```
(posts collection) 
posts =  [{
     "_id": ObjectId("601223fecb7cff30f5e198f9"),
     "user_id": ObjectId("5feb09d01292aa121551adaf")

    },
 {
     "_id": ObjectId("601229e8204fdd422f8b38d1"),
     "user_id": ObjectId("5feb0a181292aa121551adb1")
 },

     {
         "_id": ObjectId("6013a0551755a1730c6a424d"),
         "user_id": ObjectId("5feb09d01292aa121551adaf")
     }]

    (users collection) users = [{
    "_id": ObjectId("5feb09d01292aa121551adaf"),
    "name": "john doe"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5feb0a181292aa121551adb1"),
    "name": "Sim tim"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5feb09d01292aa121551adaf"),
    "name": "john sina"
}]
```

My aggregation query is as follow

```
db.posts.aggregate([
        { $match: {"users_data.name": { $regex: "john", $options: 'i' }}},
        
        { $sort: { "createdAt": -1 } },
        { $limit: 10 },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                let: { userId: "$user_id" },
                pipeline: [{
                        $match: {
                            $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$userId"] },
                        }
                    },
                ],
                as: 'users_data',
            }
        },
        {
                    $unwind: {
                        path: "$users_data",
                        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true // optional
                    }
                },
        {
            $project: {
                "users_data":"$users_data",
                "_id": 1
            }
        },
    ]);
```

This query gives me a blank array. but when I pass a blank object {} in $match filter then it gives me all record and when I search with a user name like john then gives me a blank array.

can anyone help me with this, how can I search string from users collection directly with aggregation query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You added some example of your data. But in the aggregation you use `createdAt` and `updatedAt`, also there is a match on `users_data` which is also absent in the document examples. Please update your data, or do not use those fields in the aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Evhz, Yes now I did the correction in my question and you can check above. I also tried this but it's giving a blank array. I also tried by removing all $project query from aggregation but still getting the same result. Can you please check and let me know